# How to load a part of a progressive image?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I would like to find a way to stop de loading of a huge image in a HTML page.
Maybe using Javascript and something like http range.

The purpose of this would be to have some JPG Progressive images, and loading a small part of it.

For example, I have a 2mega picture, and only need to display it on a 200px width `<img>`.

How can I do to load only the data I need, without generating any smaller image.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There is no simple answer to this question, that I know of. Most people who need something like create a back service that they can request images from, and they pass it the image id and a size (200px, for example) and the service will return the image, and using imagemagik, it will scale the image down and deliver that to the client. Purely clientside, there is no way to get a 2MB image onto the client without downloading the entire 2MB. The server would have to be responsible for scaling the original image.

Comment: To do this you would have to stream the data manually, analyze the content while streaming, abort at a suitable position in the stream, and implement a jpeg-parser that can process and render this data. It is possible, but it is quite some work, slow as hell (especially on mobile devices, wich I assume, are the reason for this request), and you still can have incompatible jpegs. I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: If you would make an attempt, what would it look like?

Comment: I was thinking about something like @Thomas said, but without the jpeg-parser part. As the browser already "know" how to display partial data (when you load a "JPEG Progressive" image, it's well shown). So maybe using the "state" of the request, stopping the stream at a suitable state...