# Download a small version of a huge image - Client side - Without backend function - javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to download different sizes of an image?

For example I have 3000*3000 px image:
https://via.placeholder.com/3000x3000

So when my javascript code runs in Android, We just need a 1000*1000 image. I know its possible to resize this image after download ( For example using canvas).

But Is it possible to download a small version of this image without running a code in backend? Just client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible without backend code. I suppose it's possible to somehow load only part progressive JPEG and it may look ok when downsized locally. Usually it is not hard to add backend code to server specific image sizes. That could work like this: https://via.placeholder.com/my_img.jpg?size=1000x1000

I found some interesting ideas here:
[How to load a part of a progressive image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796278/how-to-load-a-part-of-a-progressive-image)

Comment: Thank you JeremiahBarrar. We use Firebase and node.js in backend. Do you have any suggestion for any npm to serve picture in different sizes?

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/nodejs-image-resize-express-sharp seems good, sharp uses c++ for fast resizing

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the **srcset** attribute - which is used to give different sources of images. The srcset attribute specifies the URL of the image to use in different situations.

```
So, with these attributes in place, the browser will:

Look at its device width.
Work out which media condition in the sizes list is the first one to be true.
Look at the slot size given to that media query.
Load the image referenced in the srcset list that most closely matches the slot size.
```

The following is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

...

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

...

We can however use two new attributes — srcset and sizes — to provide several additional source images along with hints to help the browser pick the right one. You can see an example of this in our responsive.html example on Github (see also the source code):

The srcset and sizes attributes look complicated, but they're not that bad to understand if you format them as shown above, with a different part of the attribute value on each line. Each value contains a comma-separated list, and each part of the lists is made up of three sub-parts. Let's run through the contents of each now:

srcset defines the set of images we will allow the browser to choose between, and what size each image is. Before each comma, we write:

An image filename (elva-fairy-480w.jpg.)
A space.
The image's inherent width in pixels (480w) — note that this uses the w unit, not px as you might expect. This is the image's real size, which can be found by inspecting the image file on your computer (for example on a Mac you can select the image in Finder, and press Cmd + I to bring up the info screen.)
sizes defines a set of media conditions (e.g. screen widths) and indicates what image size would be best to choose, when certain media conditions are true — these are the hints we talked about earlier. In this case, before each comma we write

a media condition ((max-width:480px)) — you'll learn more about these in the CSS topic, but for now let's just say that a media condition describes a possible state that the screen can be in. In this case, we are saying "when the viewport width is 480 pixels or less".
A space.
The width of the slot the image will fill when the media condition is true (440px.)

Comment: I can't have several format of image in the storage. There is just a hight image, and I wonder if it is possible to download the low quality version.